# Flutter: Dart Error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

Hey guys I am new to Flutter and trying to build a variation selector for an eCommerce application. I am getting this error while trying to build a size variation widget for the `size-color` variation. It works for `size` only or `color` only variation. This is the error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1`.

Also, when I print the length of the array, I am getting the value 1.

The idea is to show the available sizes when someone clicks on a color that gets displayed without any issues. but while trying to show the size, facing this error.

This is the code

```
///size widget
class SelectSizeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SelectSizeWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectSizeWidgetState createState() => _SelectSizeWidgetState();
}

class _SelectSizeWidgetState extends State<SelectSizeWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ProductController>(
      builder: (_,model,__) {
        return Wrap(
          spacing: 8,
          runSpacing: 8,
          children: List.generate((model.sizeColour.isNotEmpty) ? model.ss.length : model.size.length , (index) {
            if(model.sizeColour.isNotEmpty) {
              if(model.selectedColour != null || model.selectedColour != ""){
              var _res = model.sizeColour
                  .where((element) =>
                      element.var2!.toUpperCase() == model.selectedColour)
                  .toList();
              var _size = _res[index];
              return buildSize(_size);

            } else {
                var _res = model.sizeColour.toList();
                var _size = _res[index];
                return buildSize(_size);

              }
          } else if (model.size.isNotEmpty) {
              var _size = model.size[index];
              return buildSize(_size);
            }else if(model.materialSize.isNotEmpty){
              var _res = model.materialSize.where((element) =>
              element.var1.toUpperCase() == model.selectedMaterial)
                  .toList();
              var _size = _res[index];
              return buildSize(_size);
            }else{
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          }),
        );
      }
    );
  }

  SizedBox buildSize(Variant size) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 38,
      child: RawChip(
        label: Text(size.var1),
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7, vertical: 7),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.05),
        selectedColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2),
        selected: size.varId == context.read<ProductController>().selectedVariation,
        shape: StadiumBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.05))),
        onSelected: (bool value) {
          context.read<ProductController>().setSize(size.varId);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Productcontroller - for detail

```
List<Variant> size = [];
List<Variant> colour = [];
List<Variant> sizeColour = [];
List<String> ss = [];
List<String> cc = [];


Future<bool> getProductDetails({required String slug}) async {

  final val = await ApiProvider().getProductDetails(slug: slug);
  if (val.statusCode == 200 || val.statusCode == 201) {
    product = productDetailsResponseFromJson(jsonEncode(val.data));

    /// variation
    if (product!.variants) {
      clearAll();
      List<Map<int, Set<String>>> sc = [];
      List<String> s = [];
      List<String> c = [];

      selectedVariation = product!.prdtVari.first.id;
      for (var each in product!.prdtVari) {
        var _var = each.variation.toLowerCase();
        
        if (_var == 'colour') {
          colour.add(Variant(
              varId: each.id,
              var1: each.variationTypes.first.name,
              typeMap1: each.variationTypes.first.typeMap));
          c.add(each.variationTypes.first.name);
          notifyListeners();
        } else if (_var == 'size') {
          size.add(Variant(
              varId: each.id,
              var1: each.variationTypes.first.name,
              typeMap1: each.variationTypes.first.typeMap));
          s.add(each.variationTypes.first.name);
          notifyListeners();
        } else if (_var == 'size-colour') {
          sc.add({
            each.id: {
              each.variationTypes.first.name,
              each.variationTypes.last.name
            }
          });
          sizeColour.add(Variant(
              varId: each.id,
              var1: each.variationTypes.first.name,
              typeMap1: each.variationTypes.first.typeMap,
              var2: each.variationTypes.last.name,
              typeMap2: each.variationTypes.last.typeMap));
          s.add(each.variationTypes.first.name);
          c.add(each.variationTypes.last.name);
          notifyListeners();
        } 
      }
      ss = s.toSet().toList();
      cc = c.toSet().toList();

      if(cc.isNotEmpty){
        if(product!.prdtVari.first.variation.toLowerCase() == "colour"){
          selectedColour = colour.where((element) => element.varId == selectedVariation!).first.var1.toUpperCase();
        } else if(product!.prdtVari.first.variation.toLowerCase() == "size-colour") {
          selectedColour = sizeColour.where((element) => element.varId == selectedVariation!).first.var2!.toUpperCase();
        }
      };
      notifyListeners();
    }
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return true;
  } else {
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return false;
  }
}
```

API model

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final productDetailsResponse = productDetailsResponseFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ProductDetailsResponse productDetailsResponseFromJson(String str) => ProductDetailsResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String productDetailsResponseToJson(ProductDetailsResponse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());


class ProductDetailsResponse {
  ProductDetailsResponse({

    required this.category,
    required this.title,
    required this.variants,
    required this.slug,
    required this.averageReview,
    required this.countReview,
    required this.productDetailsInfo,
    required this.prdtImg,
    required this.prdtVari,
  });

  int category;
  String title;
  bool variants;
  String slug;
  double averageReview;
  int countReview;
  ProductDetailsInfo productDetailsInfo;
  List<ProductDetailsImages> prdtImg;
  List<ProductDetailsVariation> prdtVari;

  factory ProductDetailsResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductDetailsResponse(

    category: json["category"],
    title: json["title"],
    variants: json["var"],
    slug: json["slug"],
    averageReview: json["rating"],
    countReview: json["rCount"],
    productDetailsInfo: ProductDetailsInfo.fromJson(json["prdtInfo"]),
    prdtImg: List<ProductDetailsImages>.from(json["prdtImg"].map((x) => ProductDetailsImages.fromJson(x))),
    prdtVari: List<ProductDetailsVariation>.from(json["prdtVari"].map((x) => ProductDetailsVariation.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {

    "category": category,
    "title": title,
    "var": variants,
    "slug": slug,
    "rating": averageReview,
    "rCount": countReview,
    "prdtInfo": productDetailsInfo.toJson(),
    "prdtImg": List<dynamic>.from(prdtImg.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "prdtVari": List<dynamic>.from(prdtVari.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class ProductDetailsImages {
  ProductDetailsImages({
    required  this.id,
    required  this.images,
    required  this.cover,
  });

  int id;
  String? images;
  bool cover;

  factory ProductDetailsImages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductDetailsImages(
    id: json["id"],
    images: json["images"],
    cover: json["cover"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "images": images,
    "cover": cover,
  };
}

class ProductDetailsInfo {
  ProductDetailsInfo({
    required  this.brand,
    required  this.mrp,
    required  this.price,
    required  this.inStock,
    required  this.desc,
    required  this.shipCost,
    required  this.condition,
  });

  String? brand;
  double mrp;
  double price;
  String inStock;
  String desc;
  double? shipCost;
  String condition;

  factory ProductDetailsInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductDetailsInfo(

    brand: json["brd"],
    mrp: json["mrp"],
    price: json["price"],
    inStock: json["iStock"],
    desc: json["desc"],
    shipCost: json["shCost"],
    condition: json["con"],

  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "brand": brand,
    "mrp": mrp,
    "price": price,
    "iStock": inStock,
    "desc": desc,
    "shCost": shipCost,
    "con": condition,

  };
}

class ProductDetailsVariation {
  ProductDetailsVariation({
    required this.id,
    required this.variation,
    required this.mrp,
    required this.price,
    required this.inStock,
    required this.images,
    required this.variationTypes,
  });

  int id;
  String variation;
  double mrp;
  double price;
  String inStock;
  List<ProductDetailsImages> images;
  List<ProductDetailsVariationType> variationTypes;

  factory ProductDetailsVariation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductDetailsVariation(
    id: json["id"],
    variation: json["vAtion"],
    mrp: json["mrp"],
    price: json["price"],
    inStock: json["iStock"],
    images: List<ProductDetailsImages>.from(json["imgs"].map((x) => ProductDetailsImages.fromJson(x))),
    variationTypes: List<ProductDetailsVariationType>.from(json["vTypes"].map((x) => ProductDetailsVariationType.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "vAtion": variation,
    "mrp": mrp,
    "price": price,
    "iStock": inStock,
    "imgs": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "vTypes": List<dynamic>.from(variationTypes.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class ProductDetailsVariationType {
  ProductDetailsVariationType({
    required  this.id,
    required  this.name,
    required this.typeMap,
  });
  int id;
  String name;
  String typeMap;

  factory ProductDetailsVariationType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductDetailsVariationType(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    typeMap: json["tMap"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "tMap": typeMap,
  };
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you include `ProductController`

Comment: I second that: without `ProductController` or `model` Type there isn't much we can do.

Comment: The error message is clear: you're trying to access an element that is out of range.  You say that the error comes from the `var _size = _res[index];`, but you have that line in multiple places.   It's impossible to solve your problem without understanding what the relationship is supposed to be among `_res.length`, `model.ss.length`, `model.size.length`, `model.sizeColor.length`, and `model.materialSize.length`.

Comment: If you want people to debug it for you, then you at least have to provide enough code to be able to reproduce the problem.  Otherwise the only thing that people can do is to advise you to verify that your array sizes are what you think you they should be.

Comment: Hello, Sorry for not  putting enough details, I have updated the question with controller and api model. Please do have a look. Thank you.

Comment: The code you've posted is still incomplete.  Someone cannot copy it, run it, and reproduce your problem.  You also still have no indicated what the relationship is supposed to be among `_res`, `model.ss`, `model.size`, `model.sizeColor`, and `model.materialSize`.  What do these things represent?  The code you've provided does not provide definitions for them.

Comment: Printing _res gives me `[Instance of 'Variant', Instance of 'Variant']` as it should be. I don't understand why the error shows. if I put `var _size = _res[0];, the size shows 2 or 3 times. (duplicate data)`

Answer (score 1):

`List.generate` is using `model.ss.length` or `model.size.length` to generate your list like you instructed on this line

```
List.generate((model.sizeColour.isNotEmpty) ? model.ss.length : model.size.length , (index) {
```

It means `index <= model.ss.length-1` or `index <= model.size.length-1`. Then you did

```
var _res = model.sizeColour.where((element) => element.var2!.toUpperCase() == model.selectedColour).toList();
```

So if `var _size = _res[index]` throw `RangeError` it means `_res.length < model.ss.length-1` or `_res.length < model.size.length-1` but it should be equal, so the solution is to make sure the 3 arrays have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the 'or' with 'and'

```
if(model.selectedColour != null && model.selectedColour != "")
```

Since you used or it is always true if either of the condition is met. So even it's empty that variable was assigned with empty value.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still getting this error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2`. and printing _res gives me `[Instance of 'Variant', Instance of 'Variant']` as it should be. I don't understand why the error shows.

Comment: I think you are assigning a length in the list generate and accessing that I'd in another list. Try giving 1 in place of length of list and see if this error is gone. If yes then work on fixing the correct length in list.generate

Answer (score 0):

Error often happen when you render data in list but you hasn't data you try check null in code because you not have controller call api or data any where

- you can check line code has "if" ...
- check length of list > 0
- "var _size = _res[index];" maybe index  null

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still getting this error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2`. and printing _res gives me `[Instance of 'Variant', Instance of 'Variant']` as it should be. I don't understand why the error shows.

Comment: when I print index, it is showing as 0 and 1 and not null.

Answer (score 0):

I could not read all the code and test it, but I got that error before. When?
for example,

```
    List<String> myList = [1 , 2 ,3 ,4];

child : ListView(
children: [
  Text("${mylist[0]}"),
  Text("${mylist[1]}"),
  Text("${mylist[2]}"),
  Text("${mylist[3]}"),
  Text("${mylist[4]}"),
]
) ;
```

so you have four items in the list which mean your index will be just until 3 if you add more than the items in the list it will show that error.
I hope I was able to explain.